# Cannot get the real file path - Android Oreo 8+

Tags: android, filepath, android-8.0-oreo

I'm downloading a file using Download Manager and saving into Download Folder.
After download finish i'm picking up the folder path like this way:

```
int uriIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI);
                            String downloadedPackageUriString = cursor.getString(uriIndex);
```

Then i need to use this path to unzip the file downloaded. The code to unzip it is below:

SouceFile is the path from downloadmanager.

unzip(String sourceFile, String destinationFolder)

```
try {

            zis = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(sourceFile)));
            ZipEntry ze;
            int count;

            byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            while ((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {

                String fileName = ze.getName();

                fileName = fileName.substring(fileName.indexOf("/") + 1);
                File file = new File(destinationFolder, fileName);
                File dir = ze.isDirectory() ? file : file.getParentFile();
                Log.i("MainService", "Unzipping fileName: " + fileName);

                file_path = destinationFolder + "/" + fileName;

                if (!dir.isDirectory() && !dir.mkdirs())
                    throw new FileNotFoundException("Invalid path: " + dir.getAbsolutePath());
                if (ze.isDirectory()) continue;
                FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(file);
                try {
                    while ((count = zis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        fout.write(buffer, 0, count);
                    }


                } finally {
                    fout.close();
                }

                list_filenames.add(file_downloaded);

            }
            Log.d("MainService", "TAM:" + tam);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            Log.d("MainService", "Oiiiiiiiiii " + ioe);
            return list_filenames;
        } finally {
            if (zis != null)
                try {
                    zis.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {

                }
        }
```

The code to unzip works on Android 6 (My phone), but on Android Oreo + it doesnt.

I'm getting (No such file or directory) from `zis = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(sourceFile)));`

Reinforcing: I'm not getting this error on Android 6. Just on 8+

Thanks for any help.

I tried some suggestions from other guys here with similar problem, but doesnt works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm not getting this error on Android 6

At most, you are not getting this error on the one device that you tested on Android 6.0. There are many device models running Android 6.0, not just one.

`COLUMN_LOCAL_URI` is supposed to give you a string representation of a `Uri`. That will not work with `FileInputStream`, because a `Uri` is not a file.

Replace:

```
zis = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(sourceFile)));
```

with:

```
zis = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(cr.openInputStream(Uri.parse(sourceFile))));
```

...where `cr` is a `ContentResolver` that you get by calling `getContentResolver()` on some `Context`.

Comment: Thanks. It's works. But now i'm getting permission denied from

 } catch (IOException ioe) {
            Log.d("MainService", "Oiiiiiiiiii " + ioe);. 

My app is a system mode. He comes factory installed, so users doesnt have to click nothing. But anyway, i have manyfest permissions to write and read. Have any idea what can be? Thanks again.

Comment: @ThiagoMoreira: I recommend that you post a new Stack Overflow question, with your updated code and the complete stack trace.

Comment: Sure. Thank you.